# React instance value or State for minor UI update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

In my mind, whenever I call `setState` of React Component I believe at least a little work is done to refresh the Component. To store every important dynamic variable in the state is a niche I have seen so far in the community.

Imagine this none trivial code that sets `searching` variable to true when a server request is yet to return.

```
fetchSearch = async (food) => {
        this.searching = true;
        const request = await client.get(`http://localhost:8081/food?q=${food}`);
        const results = await request.json();

        this.setState((state) => {
            this.searching = false;
            return { searchResult: results }
        });
    }


<Input showSpinner={this.searching}</Input>
```

As you may have guessed the value of `this.searching` is a determinant of if the Loading UI animation CSS class is applied.

My question is if it is really worth setting `this.searching` in the state  with the extra **WORK** of refreshing the Component, as opposed to using an instance value ? What are the possible troubles I can run into ? What benefit do I derive other than having a central store for instance ?

Comment: If you put `searching` directly on the instance instead of in state with `setState` the component will not be re-rendered, so the `showSpinner` prop will never be set to `true`. You need to put every variable that can change and that you want to use for rendering in the component state.

Comment: Setting variables directly into `this` won't update you ui, whilst `setState` will.

Comment: @Tholle I can confirm that searching is swtiching between true and false in this case and the showSpinner is receiving the switching

Comment: Then there is another state or prop update that is causing your component to re-render, but you should not rely on that. Everything that changes and is used in the rendering should be put in state.

Comment: @Tholle Makes sense, I moved  this.searching below setState and the result is unpredictable

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already updating the state for `searchResult`, updating another field `searching` will not cause additional rerenders.

If your UI relies on `searching` you will need to have it in the `state`, otherwise react would not know that `searching` value has changed.

React is already very performant, there is no need to overthink before you actually encounter any issues with the performance.